# TensorFlow Classification

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I used TensorFlow to train a model that could identify 8 categories.I want to train on the basis of the original model and increase the category to 10.I don't want to train from scratch. What should I do?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is change the output layer to 10 categories, and set the checkpoint file as the one you used for 8 categories. Then you continue training from that point on. You can research on "transfer learning" regarding this.